# C# LINQ Order List by Object property, Select X Amount

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Basically I am looking for a way in LINQ to select the first, lets say 3, grouped objects in a list.

For example, a list might contain:

{"AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "DD", "EE", "EE"}

And the list that I would want to return would be:

{"AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "DD", "EE", "EE"}

meaning it would return the first 3 of the grouped elements (and if it doesn't have 3 elements, it would return however many that it could 1,2)

What I have so far is:

```
List<Object> sorted = mainList.OrderBy(x => x.NAME).ToList();
```

which just returns the First list above.

I figure I need to use some form of

```
 .Select() or .SelectMany()
```

But I'm not quite sure how to specify to get the first X amount of every group and I haven't found anything online which shows an example of what I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the first X items in each group you'll need to group all of the items first.  After you've grouped the items `Take` allows you to get the first up-to-X items from that sequence:

```
var query = data.GroupBy(item => item.Name)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Take(3));
```